# How to fix linker error when working with openCV-4.5.2 and visual studio 2019 c++ code?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019

I'm a trying to get a visual c++ up and running with some source code I found that uses OpenCV. I'm have some experience with c++. I'm getting unresolved external symbol errors and I've spent hours reading every article I can find on here about it, and every answer is... "don't link x86 with x64 libs, or vise versa" or "add x references to preferences->linker" or "add your lib/dll files to the project folder, and then add them to your solution" or "obviously you didn't add the libs to your linker".

I've already done all of the following, and it didn't work...

1. I added "c:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)" to my "VC++ Directories" in Project->Preferences->VC++ Directories. Didn't help a bit.
2. I added "c:\opencv\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)" to my Project->Preferences->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories. Didn't help.
3. I added "opencv_world452.lib Didn't help. also tried "opencv_world452.dll"
4. added environment variable to %OPENCV_DIR%\bin

It does not appear to be any of these things. Does anyone know a solution to this error that does not involve any of these things I already tried?

Here are some of the errors I'm getting:

error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unZTl.png)

Comment: Sorted by not using the opencv 4.5.2 eXe. I had to use manually install. Now everything works fine. If anyone needs help. Let me know. Happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted by not using the opencv 4.5.2 eXe. I had to use manually install. Now everything works fine. If anyone needs help. Let me know. Happy to help

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.